# Working on an FPGA without an IDE

Tags: fpga, development-tools

I've been programming microcontrollers for about 5 years now.  In my current MCU development workflow, I use [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to edit my firmware, I compile with [arm-none-eabi-gcc](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download), and I flash code with a [segger j-link tool](https://www.segger.com/jlink-debug-probes.html), all on Linux.

I love this arrangement because I can do hours of work without touching my mouse, and I don't need to go through a verbose and sloppy GUI interface just to add compiler flags ([I'm looking at you, Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m685530.aspx)).  Instead, I can just edit the makefile right there in my emacs window.

However, there is a very large FPGA project in my near future, and while I love designing hardware in verilog, I'm **absolutely not** looking forward with mucking with utter rubbish like [Microsemi's Libero](http://www.microsemi.com/products/fpga-soc/design-resources/design-software/libero-soc) or [Altera's Quartus](https://www.altera.com/downloads/download-center.tablet.html) (both of which I had the misfortune of using for very small projects).

Does anyone know which manufacturer's chip I will have to spring for if I want to compile my verilog, configure chip options, and generate the programming files ALL at the command line?  Has anyone even had success with doing something like this?

Comment: You can [easily] do this with Xilinx tools.  I've written scripts that do everything from synthesize (not compile) my verilog to program the fpga itself.

Comment: No surprise then that Xilinx has the lion's share of the FPGA market :)

Comment: I'd be surprised if you couldn't do this with Altera tools.  It's probably a pain, but I have to imagine you could do it.  If you open ISE (xilinx's older toolchain -- not super familiar with vivado) you can actually see the command line arguments etc that are being called to integrate their spaghetti tools (one of the reasons they built vivado)

Comment: Answered below, but Altera will do GNU Makefiles, and you can do Tcl scripts for Actel and Xilinx. I use scons to drive FPGA builds as part of a CI build system with Jenkins -- actually works fairly well.

Comment: Are you aware that emacs is a GUI and no TUI? Doing digital design without GUI is not possible. Yes you can compile it with make or Tcl files, but there will be a point in time when you need to debug your HDL code! How do you analyze waveforms? Print it on endless paper? Using GUIs does not mean to use the mouse .... and by the way: Quatus is one of the better EDA GUIs compared to others. If you are familar with Eclise, look for Sigasi.

Comment: @Doov Use Vivado and you'll think of ISE as a master piece of software engineering ... Vivado is on the market for 4 year not include the timr it was called PlanAhead ... it's full of bugs and has not reached all features from old ISE ...

Comment: @Paebbels  It's not a GUI by the most pedantic of definitions, but I can use it without my mouse, so that makes it a TUI in my book :).  As far as debugging goes, I usually make a testbench that shows me my waveforms in a TUI using ncurses with VPI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The state of FPGA EDA tools is awful, in my opinion.

That said, here's my tool-flow for each of the major vendors:

1. Design / initial work is done with the GUI they provide. No way around this, especially if you want to use IP Cores. This is on Windows. You can run the GUIs on Linux as well, but in the past, the Windows versions have gotten the most attention / support.
2. Compilation is done headlessly on remote Linux boxes.

The tool-flow for each is primarily Tcl-based, and if you look at what the GUI does, it's basically executing Tcl commands. Each vendor has a reference manual describing what you can do with Tcl. Altera additionally allows you to write vanilla GNU Makefiles to run Quartus headlessly.

I use scons to run Actel and Xilinx builds right now -- Python calls to Tcl scripts that execute the tools. I can't comment on Lattice, but I bet they have something similar.

Last "complaint"/note: version control can be tricky with the amount of extra crap the GUI tools spit out. My MO is to minimize the set of files to version control, and spawn the generated IP cores / project files dynamically each build, and add those to .gitignore.

Summary: You can drive Altera, Xilinx and Actel/Microsemi IDEs headless-ly with Tcl-based scripting.

Comment: oof.  Windows is a dealbreaker for me.  When you say "use the IP Cores", are you talking about ARM or DSP cores that may be baked-in to the hardware, or are you talking about proprietary softcores that are flashed on?  I am ok with foregoing proprietary softcores.

Comment: Kind of both, actually -- like, for the Xilinx Zynq, you configure the ARM hard-core in Vivado and generate a hand-off file to pass to SDK to generate the FSBL, etc. Otherwise, I'm mostly referring to vendor IP like AXI UARTs, IIC controllers, etc -- things like that.

Comment: And now to be fair, there are Linux GUI versions of say Vivado and Libero, just *personally* in my experience with support engineers and those products, they are treated as second-class citizens to the Windows product. IMO, Windows for design, and then Linux to run your builds if you have a build-server / CI process.

Comment: "Windows for design."  you're gonna make me cry, man.

Comment: One legitimate issue that I'm having here is that my research group operates entirely in the linux space, and I think my advisor would be **strongly** opposed to running any development on windows.  I can see him paying me for a month of work just to make FPGA design happen on something that's not windows.

Comment: I believe you can do everything you need to in Linux -- just be warned that the GUI experience may not be the smoothest :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38454/discussion-between-johnny-boy-and-krunal-desai).

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully driven both the Xilinx ISE and Altera Quartus toolchains from makefiles in linux. Occasionally I have had to use various gui tools to generate configuration files for various components and then use makefiles to drive the generation of the actual hdl/netlist from that with makefiles (coregen, megafunctions, qsys, etc.). Vivado is a slightly different animal, though. I think that one may require using more tcl. Though, it may be possible to connect that with makefiles in some way. I am not familiar with any other vendor software.

The example designs here contain makefile driven flows for both ISE and Quartus: https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-ethernet/